# I am reading a text file using Python but I would like to delete any text within the txt file that comes between /* and /*

Tags: python, json, text-files, readfile

I am reading a text file using Python but I would like to delete any text within the txt file that comes between /* and /*

That is how I am starting my code:

```
import json
record = []
with open('txtfile.txt, 'r') as f:
   for line in f:
```

my text file begins with:

```
/*
Changelog:
2019-11-19: Modification reading tickets 25/1
2015-02-22: ticket number 001433
/*
```

I don't want to read those lines before continuing my task. I would like to remove any text that comes in between /* and /* if any is found.

Comment: What have you tried so far? (this should be very simple to achieve using `re.sub`)

Comment: is there a way I can do it without using external libraries? I tried using strip but it didnt work for me. If you have a method please let me know. Any text between /* and /* needs to be removed as well as the characters "/*"

Comment: The `re` library is a Python built-in library; what do you mean by "external" libraries?

Comment: Ah okay, what syntax would you implement to do that using the re library?

Comment: Is it always the first 5 lines that you need to skip or can there be varying numbers of lines between lines starting with '/*' ? Does the first line always begin with '/*' ?

Comment: Nope, there are multiple lines that include /* ... /*. So what I need to do is that whenever in the text I find /* .. /* then I need to remove those characters and any text in between them

Comment: Why not post your text file’s contents for the first 10 or so lines.  Then also post what you want as a result.  That way candidate solutions can be run rather than talked about (*this should be very simple*).  Add in anything you’ve done so far.  Questions : can it recur multiple times?

Comment: All I'm trying to achieve now is that if there are any /* text */ within the text (if it occurs at any line, yes it occur multiple times) then I want to remove them using strip.

Comment: Why, specifically, do you want to use strip when it's not necessary?

Comment: If you dont post actual data and output you are asking people to write their own to test: extra barrier to answering question.  Your choice.  Also now you are using ` /* text */` common comment markers but before you had ` /* text /*`. Which is it?   SO is messing up the formatting but slash-star star-slash or slash-star star-slash?

Comment: A correct solution must be based on a FSM in order NOT to alter any strings should they contain the `/* .. */` characters by change.

Comment: the correct format is /* ........ */

Answer (score 1):

This code will open the file and print all the non-comment lines. If you'd like them written to a file you can open a file for writing and do a write instead of a print.

I've assumed you only have cases like in your example text - the comments are surrouned by `/*` and `*/` which are each on a line of their own.  This approach will not work for comments like `/* comment stuff */`, but it could be extended to support them.

```
with open("txtfile.txt") as f:
    lines_iter = iter(f)
    
    try:
        while True:
            line = next(lines_iter)

            if line.strip() != "/*":
                print(line, end="")

            else:  # In the comment block.
                while next(lines_iter).strip() != "*/":
                    pass

    except StopIteration:
        pass
```

Comment: `"but you must /* keep this */ in a string"`

Comment: What is I have a comment like: /*Audit Fields END*/ --- Where the /* and */ are attached to the letters in between

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that there is only ever (at most) one pair of /* delimiters.

Read the entire file into memory. Look for 1st delimiter. If found, look for 2nd delimiter. If found reconstruct text using traditional slicing techniques

Assume the file contents are:

```
Banana
/*
Changelog:
2019-11-19: Modification reading tickets 25/1
2015-02-22: ticket number 001433
/*
Hello world
Goodbye cruel world
The end
```

Then:

```
FILENAME = 'txtfile.txt'
DELIMITER = '/*'

with open(FILENAME) as f:
    data = f.read()
    while (p1 := data.find(DELIMITER)) >= 0:
        if (p2 := data.find(DELIMITER, p1+len(DELIMITER))) >= 0:
            data = data[:p1] + data[p2+len(DELIMITER)+1:]
        else:
            break
    print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
Banana
Hello world
Goodbye cruel world
The end
```

Comment: That's amazing thanks - What if I have multiple pairs of delimters within the text file?

Comment: @user31081998 Just wrap the above code in a loop that terminates when no more delimiters are found. See edited code

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem. I have tried using sort of a toggle that skips rows after the `/*`. Please refer to the inline comments for details:

```py
with open(r"C:\Temp\my_text.log") as log:
    # init toggle
    toggle = 1
    for row in log:
        # if row delimiter is found 'toggle off' the variable
        # to ignore subsequent rows until it is encountered again. Then
        # toggle it on.
        if row.strip() == "/*":
            toggle = (not toggle)
        # if is toggled make sure the row is not the delimiter itself
        if toggle and row.strip() != "/*":
            print(row.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little JSON parser to play with. It knows if it is parsing in a string or not. Not a ready to use solution, but all you need is to remove parts beginnig one char before the transition to the `ML_COMMENT` state and ending at position where the transition from the `ML_COMMENT` occurs.

```
import enum

State = enum.Enum('State', 'JSON STRING ESCAPE SLASH ML_COMMENT ML_COMMENT_END')

TRANS = { 
    State.JSON: {
        '/': State.SLASH,
        '"': State.STRING,
    },  
    State.STRING: {
        '\\': State.ESCAPE,
        '"': State.JSON,
    },  
    State.ESCAPE: {
        'default': State.STRING,
    },  
    State.SLASH: {
        '*': State.ML_COMMENT,
        'default': State.JSON,
    },  
    State.ML_COMMENT: {
        '*': State.ML_COMMENT_END,
    },  
    State.ML_COMMENT_END: {
        '/': State.JSON,
        '*': State.ML_COMMENT_END,
        'default': State.ML_COMMENT,
    },  
}

def strip(json_str):
    state = State.JSON
    for ch in json_str:
        trans = TRANS[state]
        try:
            new = trans[ch]
        except KeyError:
            new = trans.get('default', state) 
        if new != state:
            print(f"{ch} {state.name} -> {new.name}")
            state = new 
        else:
            print(ch)

TEST=r'[10/*comment*/, /***also comment***/ "/*not comment*/", "abc\"/*still in string*/",null]'

strip(TEST)
```