# Get a new line after removing comment in C program file with python

Tags: python, comments

1st code

[image: 1]

2nd code

[image: 2]

```
copy = open("output.txt", "w")
with open('code.txt',"r") as f:
   for line in f:
     line = line.split('/',1 )[0]
     copy.write(line)
copy=open("output.txt","r")
print(copy.read())
```

here it removes a comment by deleting the separate line where the comment is deleted. I want to keep a new line space where the comment was deleted in the C program.

Comment: In C, a comment  does not start at any slash (e.g. `a = b / 2;`) and does not end at the end of line in the case of  `/* ... */`.

Comment: @VPfB And in the case of `/* ... */`, a comment can also span multiple lines. Use regex to handle all cases more easily.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

with open('code.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read()
    newlines = re.sub(r'/\*.*\*/', '\n', lines, flags=re.DOTALL)

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(newlines)
```

re.DOTALL allows you to capture a pattern across lines

Comment: OK in most cases, but beware: `puts("/*"); some C statements here; puts("*/");`

Comment: Agreed. In order to detect that, would need some form of syntax parser to detect and ignore such cases.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Few weeks ago I posted a skeleton of a parser for removing JSON comments: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72465641/5378816